# Merge sort algorithm - the implementation in java

Tags: java

Is the anybody who can give a link where is explained the implementation of merge sort algorithm in java? I understand how the algorithm works but I don't know how to implement it in java. What I have found on the internet couldn't make me to figure out what is doing each  condition or loop of the code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read Knuth. Map to Java in your mind.

Comment: Use google. Seriously, there are examples using Java with comments. If you understand Java and the Merge sort, you should understand it.

Comment: in english: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/,  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html ...in german: https://javabeginners.de/Algorithmen/Sortieralgorithmen/Mergesort.php https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithmensammlung:_Sortierverfahren:_Mergesort, http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/merge/merge.htm source: 
 http://www.google.com/search?q=mergesoft+java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at

```
java.util.TimSort
```

But it hard to understand, I don't recommend if you're beginner.
Better one is

```
java.util.Arrays::legacyMergeSort
```

more simple but out of date implementaion.